# Why do we use InternalsVisibleToAtrribute even after giving the reference of one project to another in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I made 2 projects in which there are internal members and i want to call some internals from one function, say funcA, to another project. So I gave reference of the project to another. Why will i use the InteralsVisibleToAttribute if by giving the reference would make it visible in the project?

Comment: Using `InteralsVisibleTo` is a code smell. Breaking encapsulation like that means that you haven't properly encapsulated your logic. At that point, you might as well just declares the methods in question `public` and be done with it.

Comment: Are you referring to Inter**n**alsVisibleTo with an additional _"n"_ in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment, the use of `InternalsVisibleTo` is a code smell (something that may make the code look poor). The only "correct" use of it is for unit testing, where you want to be able to test internal methods without making them public for all library users.

As to the "why", that's what it is for. `InternalsVisibleTo` is used to declare that any elements (methods, classes or fields) inside that library that are declared `internal` are to be seen as if they where public *for the indicated library only*. So a declaration such as

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyLibraryUnitTest, PublicKey=....")]
```

tells the compiler that any internal members of this library are to be made visible for `MyLibraryUnitTest`.

Comment: This is more of a philosophical debate, but I'd say it's a code smell **even for unit testing**. Testing should take place via a the public surface area of the class. If you have logic so complex that it's difficult to test via the public surface area, your class is probably too complicated and should be decomposed into multiple, easily-testable components that you can compose together.

Comment: @DanielMann I would say that depends on how your public api is organized. E.g. if you use the factory pattern a lot, you might have large classes that are not visible at all from outside.